# unable to set href inside click event of Jquery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to set href using Jquery inside click event of RadioButtonList but that doesnt work If I take the same code to document.ready event it works fine but not in click event. Please advice.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
   url = "Results.aspx?latitude=" +latitude + "&Longitude=" + longitude;

 $("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr("href", url); // this works..
        }        
        $('.rbl input').click(function() {

            id = $(this).parent().children("input").val();
            url = "Results.aspx?latitude=" + latitude + "&Longitude=" + longitude + "&ServiceCenterProductTypeId=" + id;
            //alert(url);
            $("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr("href", url); //this doesnt work....

        });
    });
```

Comment: Where is longitude and latitude set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (probably) have the `AutoPostBack` property set to true, causing a postback to the server which reloads the entire page.

Therefore, your changes in Javascript are overwritten by the postback.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like you have an extra closing curly bracket `}` after this line:

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr("href", url); // this works..
```